# Sending multiple request from client side to php with js

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to send multiple requests at once via console. But it stops because of alert boxes or something else, maybe it's a CORS related thing(I'm not sure). I am trying to do something like automatic request sender with preset values. **I am just wondering. Is it possible to perform something like this?**

I applied iteration to input fields with a simple for loop. I tried code on x site via console but it iterates only once(it worked without any error)

**(code is a bit different than this => no sendReq() function, no viewResults() function and inside the for loop there was a button.click() action)**

Here is my simulation for this. (It works on JSBin) :

```js
var firstInput = document.getElementById('input_first');
var secondInput = document.getElementById('input_second');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
 
function sendReq() {
    var datas= { 
       'Input 1 Value 1' : 'input 2 value 1',
       'Input 1 Value 2' : 'input 2 value 2',
    };

    for (var x in datas) {
        firstInput.value = x;
        secondInput.value = datas[x];
        // button.click();
        run(firstInput.value, secondInput.value); 
    }
}

function run(first, second) {
   alert(first + "=" + second);
}

/* function action() {
    alert(firstInput.value + secondInput.value)
} */

sendReq();
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="input_first" type="text">
    <input id="input_second" type="text">
    <button id="button" onclick="action()">test</button>
</form>
```

My purpose is send every single data to input fields then click after every single iteration. But this iterates only once on a real site. What is the logical error? Thanks for your answers anyway

Comment: `alert` is **synchrounous**, while requests from client side to server side are **asynchrounous** (unless you're forcing them to be sync), that means that your input values will always show the last request you send (the request will be correct, though), because **while the request is performed, the next for index is looped, since it's NOT synchrounous**. Do you have any console error in your real site? If so, may you please at least provide the error type?

Comment: hi @briosheje, it just returned undefined but there was no error. Just added the first value and then stopped execution. Your answer is correct there is async - sync problem. I think this won't work anyway unless i can control on server side :/

Comment: server side should be independent. Sending multiple requests to the server is (of course) possible and can be done in a lot of ways according to your needs, so I guess the error is likely somewhere else, but we need to see more code in order to know where the issue is. A little tip I can give you is that if you are performing an HTTP call and you're getting a `Promise` returned, keep in mind that if you don't handle the **.catch** event (the http call error) and there is an error in your **success** callback, the error won't be shown.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/a-guide-to-automating-scraping-the-web-with-javascript-chrome-puppeteer-node-js-b18efb9e9921 I found a library on there. It's related about promise based automation(as you mentioned above) i am going to try it.